# Best way to validate multiple fields in a request

Tags: python, flask

I wanted to run by you guys to check what's the best way to validate multiple fields. I am building a web app with Flask which is basically an endpoint to take a POST call do some processing and create resources in the cloud.

Here is my situation, considering this is my API call:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "field1": "project-name",
    "field2": "12345-6789-4212",
    "field3": "dev"
}'
```

Now, on my code I want to validate all fields in the request:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def main():
    field1 = request.json['field1']
    field2 = request.json['field2']
    field3 = request.json['field3']
    
    if validate_name(field1) == False:
       return jsonify(message='Nope'), 400
    if field3 not in ["dev", "prod"]:
       return jsonify(message='Nope'), 400
    if field2 not in ["12345-6789-4212", "12345-4489-4212"]:
       return jsonify(message='Nope'), 400
    try:
       //my code here
       return 200
    except:
       //return 400
```

Considering I have about 10 fields in my request body. Is this if / return chain the best way to validate each field? Is this the best code structure for this case? The validation is different for each one of them so I'd assume yes but want to check with you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group all the checks into the one condition with `or` Boolean operator:

```
if not validate_name(field1) or \
   field3 not in ["dev", "prod"] or \
   field2 not in ["12345-6789-4212", "12345-4489-4212"]:
    return jsonify(message='Nope'), 400
```

Comment: Agree but I might need to return different messages to the client depending on what condition failed. I don't think I have a better way of doing that besides how I did it in this case right?

Comment: Is the goal to return information about the first inconsistency or all inconsistencies?
Is it possible for more than one condition to be true at the same time?

Comment: The goal is to return information about the first inconsistency found. I can wrap all that in a function and call/validate it and return a message. Would that be a better way do to this? I am just looking for best practice from a code perspective but not sure if I can get a way around that since each if condition needs to be in place to return something to the client.

Comment: In my opinion, under these conditions, your solution is quite optimal.  Perhaps others will have different ideas. I recommend editing your question to indicate that each check returns different values.